# Male/female jumper wires for really small and close-to-each-other pins

Tags: soldering, pins, jumper

I have a 20 pin 'male to male' 1mm pitch connector as shown in the included picture (I'm not sure if it's the correct name).

One side will be soldered to the board, and the pins on the other side need to be connected to USB, or a serial port.

The question is - what is the easiest way to do it? My soldering skills are not the best, and soldering wires to the really close together pins might be difficult. Are there male/female jumper wires so small that could make this process easy? I guess I would need less than 0,5mm female part of the jumper wires to be able to expose all the pins.

All suggestions are highly appreciated!

[image: Pins to solder to]

Comment: I am not sure but have you checked the "arduino" jumper wires if that will fit?

Comment: Yes, those are too big - 0,1 inch. The distance between connectors are is only 1mm in this case.

Comment: Looks like a standard SMD double row header or am I missing something? Where's the "male to male"? Are you asking how to take one of the pins from the mounted connector and connect it to a wire without risking a short with the ones next to it?

Comment: What you could do is to get a 1mm pitch connector and some wires/cable. Example: [link](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/JST-SH-1mm-Pitch-JST-power_60567747908.html)

Comment: Another thing you could do is to directly solder the wires on the pins, and using 
heat shrink tubing to prevent shorts between them. Since you have stated earlier that you're not good at soldering, maybe heat shrink them one by one?

Comment: @Capt.Frost that is a dual row pin header, the JST connector shell would not work ... but a JST pin with heatshrink tubing may actually work